# Ref of routeur-outlet return NG04012 error when trying to access to activatedRoute

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-animations

I want to run an animation based on the path parameter of the route so to do that I need to my param id like that :

```js
  prepareRoute(outletRef: RouterOutlet) {
    const id = outletRef.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id; //ERROR Error: NG04012: Outlet is not activated
    // Note : id is a number
    return id ? id : 0;
  }
```

and I call my function here :

```html
<!-- Note : my animation is triggered by :increment and :decrement -->
<main [@animTbdSlider]="prepareRoute(outletRef)">
  <router-outlet #outletRef="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

And my route looks like that :

```js
{
    path: AppPrimaryRoutes.MY_PRIMARY_ROUTE,
    component: DumyPageContainer,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DumyContainer,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: DumyContainer,
      },
   ],
},
```

I'm expeting the `outletRef.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id` to be undefined when we are at the `''` route and set with the id when we are at the `:id` route. An not to throw an NG04012 error.